# Which one is natural? some place where nobody is, some place where there is nobody

Tags: difference, relative-adverbs

I am making up some sentence out of my head.
But I am not sure which one is correct or natural.

> You don't need to look for some place **where nobody is**.
>   You don't need to look for some place **where there is nobody**.

and, Can I exchange "nobody" with "none/no one"?

Comment: I suppose in theory it's "grammatical", but in practice nobody would ever use your first version, and probably only poets would think of including ***none*** in any contexts like this. But ***no-one / nobody*** is really just a stylistic choice - they're effectively equivalent and interchangeable in almost all contexts. Actually, even your second version isn't particularly likely - it would be more common to refer to *some **uninhabited / deserted / desolate** place*, or *some place nobody **goes*** (where ***where*** is *optional*).

Comment: Idiomatically, we seem to prefer to place the negation in the copula rather than in the complement, e.g.:  _"You don't need to look for some place where there **isn't anybody**"_.